# apollo-state-link does not hold state in cache when page is refreshed

Tags: react-apollo, next.js, apollo-link-state

I noticed that when I update my cache locally on the clientside and it routes to another page, the cache persists with the data.

However, when I refresh that page, the cache is cleared. Is there a way to keep the cache state even after refreshing?

Answer (score 2):

Apollo's InMemoryCache is, well, in-memory, so it's not persisted between page loads. The recommended way to persist your cache is to use [apollo-cache-persist](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist). Example usage:

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { persistCache } from 'apollo-cache-persist'

const cache = new InMemoryCache({...})

persistCache({
  cache,
  storage: window.localStorage,
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  // other client options
})
```

For advanced configuration and usage, check the repo. Also, be aware if you're using SSR, there are [known issues](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist/issues/32) with using this library. You could also checkout [apollo-cache-instorage](https://github.com/TallerWebSolutions/apollo-cache-instorage), which might be more SSR-friendly.